# AppleScript: problem after upgare to Ventura: buttonnot found

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-ventura

I have a simple script that automates the command "Export Library" in Music.  It does the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Music"
        set libmenu to menu item "Library" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Export Library…" of menu of libmenu
        tell window 1
            click button "Save"
            tell sheet 1 to click button "Replace"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

(So basically it opens the menu and clicks the obvious buttons, saving me a few clicks).  However, after upgrading to Ventura (macOS 13.0), this stopped working.  The command `click button "Save"` is failing with:

```
Can’t get button \"Save\" of window 1 of process \"Music\"."
```

I tried to say `click button 1` or `click button 2` instead, but that doesn't work.  I then said `name of every button` and it printed

```
{missing value, missing value, missing value}
```

I couldn't find a good manual for AppleScript, but it does look like something changed in Ventura.  Any hints will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: That is one of the problems with GUI scripting - you need to figure out the new object hierarchy when the UI gets changed.  I don’t have Ventura to post an answer, but instead of clicking the button(s), use `get UI elements` and start exploring (viewing the event in the log), adding found elements such as `group`, `splitter group`, etc, to the window tell statement to see what UI elements are in those until you find the desired element.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that .  I should note that the UI hasn't changed, it's still exactly the same window with the same button.

Comment: It depends on how it is built - a UI can look the same but have its elements arranged in a different order, for example controls can be declared in a different order or grouped in a different view.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I replaced `click button "Save"` with:

```
        repeat with b in (get buttons)
            if name of b is "Save" then
                click b
            end if
        end repeat
```

Interestingly, I can still click the "Replace" button directly without resorting to a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: PS sorry about the typo in the subject line!  Obviously I meant "upgrade to Ventura"

Comment: Actually this doesn't work, or at least not all the time.  

I added `log (name of b)` in the loop and it keeps saying "missing value".   I wish I knew what to ask instead, but I don't see any docs on how to examine these objects.

Answer (score 0):

OK!  I found a hint for the answer [here](https://community.roonlabs.com/t/applescript-to-export-music-app-xml-nightly/102750):  Just add a short delay before trying to click on "Save"!

```
        delay 0.5
        click button "Save"
```

Without the delay, the the dialog doesn't seem to be ready and indeed if you do `get buttons` you will only see the 3 from the top left corner (close, minimize, zoom).  With the delay, `get buttons` returns 6 buttons, including the "Save".